# Getmail: Can it remove deleted messages?

Tags: windows, command-line, email, gmail, imap

I understand that [getmail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getmail) can download messages via IMAP. *But what
about deleted messages? Can I set up getmail to remove deleted messages
also from the local disk?*

Background: I’m looking for a command line client that can sync
(one-way) a Gmail account via IMAP to the local disk. Operating system
is Windows.